# How to delete columns in a dataset that have binomial variables

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

The dataset named `data` has both categorical and continuous variables.  I would like to the delete categorical variables.

I tried:

`data.1 <- data[,colnames(data)[[3L]]!=0]`

No error is printed, but categorical variables stay in data.1. Where are problems ?

The summary of "head(data)" is

```
id        1,2,3,4,... 
age       45,32,54,23,...
status    0,1,0,0,...
 ...
(more variables like as I wrote above)
```

All variables are defined as "Factor".

Comment: Please update this question to provide more/clearer information, according to the various comments below: otherwise it's likely to get (more) downvoted/closed ...

Comment: Thanks for providing more information. The fact that all variables are defined as factor makes me think that you used `read.table` to get the data and forgot `header=TRUE` ... the results of `str` would be slightly more helpful ...

Comment: @Ben Boker,thank you for kind advice. I got the data read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE).The last row of some columns are levels.  
Summary of str(data) is $id : int 1 2 3 4 ... $age : Factor w/ 24 levels "41","42","43","48",...:"46","50","78",.. $pre.treat :Factor w/3 levels "0","1","(yes)vs(no)":1,1,1,... $status :int 0 0 0 0 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do with that code? First of all, colnames(data) is not a list so using [[]] doesn't make sense. Second, The only thing you test is whether the third column name is not equal to zero. As a column name can never start with a number, that's pretty much always true. So your code translates to :

```
data1 <- data[,TRUE]
```

Not what you intend to do.

I suppose you know the meaning of binomial. One way of doing that is defining your own function `is.binomial()` like this :

```
is.binomial <- function(x,na.action=c('na.omit','na.fail','na.pass'){
    FUN <- match.fun(match.arg(na.action))
    length(unique(FUN(x)))==2
}
```

in case you want to take care of NA's. This you can then apply to your dataframe :

```
data.1 <- data[!sapply(data,is.binomial)]
```

This way you drop all binomial columns, i.e. columns with only two distinct values.

Comment: ,Thank you for correcting my bad understanding on a basic of R. Im newbee so your advice is much useful for me.
I tried your elegant function "is.binomial" to my data, 
but I got an error  'undefined columns selected' .
Is this error caused by the type of data ?
the variables of this data is Factor.

Comment: That means you have no binomial variables, i.e. no binomial variables with only 2 values. You can check that with table(). If I look at your comment on the question, you have a problem with your data. If you have a factor with 3 levels where there are only supposed to be 2 (i.e. pre.treat), check your data again.

Comment: ,I appreciate kindly instructing.I tried table() and ,as you taught, there is third variable "yes vs no",the last row of the original csv file for indicate levels.
data.1 <- data[!sapply(data,is.binomial)] 
worked after I removed the row on [excel] and run again. 
I removed the row by 
data <- data[-nrow(data),]
,and checked that had worked by tail(data).I cant understand why the row remained.

Comment: @ShimpeiMorimoto : It is defined as a level of the factor (which is NOT the same as a variable), so regardless whether you delete it or not, it will remain a level of the factor. Yet, the is.binomial() function should give TRUE now. You can drop the value level by using data$pretreat <- factor(data$pretreat)

Comment: PS : If you have an answer that solved your problem, you should accept it as the correct answer (see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) ). It will make people more prone to answer subsequent questions.

Comment: ,I'm encouraged much by your kindness.I tried <-factor() and checked it had worked on data. I would like to accept your answer as the correct one .

Answer (score 0):

@Shimpei Morimoto,

I think you need a different approach. 
Are the categorical variables defines in the dataframe as factors?
If so you can use:

> data.1 <- data[,!apply(data,2,is.factor)]

The test you perform now is if the colname number 3L is not 0.
I think this is not the case.

Another approach is

> data.1 <- data[,-3L]

works only if 3L is a number and the only column with categorical variables

Comment: The categorical variables is not determined as factors in my data , and some columns are categorical and others not . So ,in this case , I cant applicate your help but in other case that matches I would like to be much obliged to your this kindness. Thank you.

Comment: @ Shimpei Morimoto, Can you post the results from head(data), colnames(data), and mayby summary. If I have a bit more information about your data structure I might be able supply a correct answer

Comment: Check `sapply`, which is quite a better option to do this than apply.

Comment: @ Mischa Vreeburg, Thank you for your kindly fllowing.
The summary of "head(data)"  is

 id      1,2,3,4,...
 age     45,32,54,23,...
 status  0,1,0,0,...
 ...     (all variables are determined as  "Factor" )

Comment: @Mischa Vreeburg,I would solve this problem by reforming my data with acceptable to your advice, by deleting a row for "Levels" ,the last row of my data, to converte the variables to "int.". And adding rows for "levels" to binomial columns to define them as Factors.Now i'm not along with the data and programme ,so I would try later and the result will be posted to this comment.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting there, with your last comment to @Mischa Vreeburg.  It might make sense (as you suggest) to reformat your original data file, but you should also be able to solve the problem within R.  I can't quite replicate the `undefined columns` error you got.

Construct some data that look as much like your data as possible:

```
X <- read.csv(textConnection(
"id,age,pre.treat,status
  1,'27', 0,0
  2,'35', 1,0
  3,'22', 0,1
  4,'24', 1,2
  5,'55', 1,3
   ,  ,yes(vs)no,"),
  quote="\"'")
```

Take a look:

```
str(X)

'data.frame':   6 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id       : int  1 2 3 4 5 NA
 $ age      : int  27 35 22 24 55 NA
 $ pre.treat: Factor w/ 3 levels " 0"," 1","yes(vs)no": 1 2 1 2 2 3
 $ status   : int  0 0 1 2 3 NA
```

Define @Joris Mey's function:

```
is.binomial <- function(x,na.action=c('na.omit','na.fail','na.pass')) {
    FUN <- match.fun(match.arg(na.action))
    length(unique(FUN(x)))==2
}
```

Try it out: you'll see that it does *not* detect `pre.treat` as binomial, and keeps all the variables.

```
sapply(X,is.binomial)
X1 <- X[!sapply(X,is.binomial)]
names(X1)
## keeps everything
```

We can drop the last row and try again:

```
X2 <- X[-nrow(X),]
sapply(X2,is.binomial)
```

It is true in general that R does not expect "extraneous" information such as level IDs to be in the same column as the data themselves.  On the one hand, you can do even better in the R world by simply leaving the data as their original, meaningful values ("no", "yes", or "healthy", "sick" rather than 0, 1); on the other hand the data take up *slightly* more space if stored as a text file, and, more important, it becomes harder to incorporate other meta-data such as units in the file along with the data ...

Comment: @ Ben Bolker,(Thank you for your kindly introduction to the R world and "stackoverflow.com" . I also think that the data should be manupilated on R , and it would be pleasant to not make much extra-R files as ".csv" files. I run your script and learned how it is important knowing ,also showing clearly the structure of the data to analysis and data manupilating.)

Comment: @ Ben Bolker,
When I applicated on my original data,
 data <- data[-nrow(data),]
the variables remain being Factors in the result of str(data),and the Levels is. But the last row ,"a row for Levels" are not in tail(data).  
and when I deleted "the row for Lebels" on excel and run read.csv 
 the variables were defined as integer.Is the type of variables defined when the data imported? I learned in your example data that the type of variables are coerced to a type that is match. I would like to understand why this differnce occurs between "read.csv()" and "read.csv(textConnection())"